# Is there a way to disable CE Cache DB references?

Tags: database, cache, ce-cache

We have a heavily trafficked site, where we keep running to bottleneck issues with cache trying to clear and that bogging things down.

The issue is the DATABASE is being taxed by CE Cache maintaining the list of cached files.

Additionally, when we've tested clearing the cache via the admin, it doesn't seem to actually clear the DB references, nor the files on the server.

Is there a setting that would allow us to NOT record the references in the database at all? (We do not use the admin to clear the caches so we don't really need the DB references, and it doesn't seem to really work well anyway). If we could disable this somehow, I think that would be a significant help!

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT / a bit more info:

**EE:** v5.3.2
**CE Cache:** v2.0.2
**Cache Driver**: "dummy"
**PHP:** v 7.2.33

Comment: As is routinely stated in replies to questions in this forum, you will greatly enhance the chance of a useful reply to your questions if you include within them the versions of EE and php that you are using, and where relevant (this case being one of them) the versions of the EE add-ons you are using!  EE behaviour is strongly affected by version number, as sometimes are addons.  Thanks!

Comment: What cache driver are you using?

Comment: Sorry bout that, posted quickly and didn't provide enough environment info, have updated my question. Thank you!

Comment: @ByteMyPixel If it is an option, I would *highly* recommend switching to the static cache driver. It's as fast as Apache or NginX can server a flat file, which is as fast as you can get. The static cache driver circumvents the EE system all together.

Comment: Unfortunately static wasn't an option for us on this particular instance (partly due to conflicts with other addons, & partly due to issues with other custom "middleware" we have integrating w/ CartThrob), we have EE native cacheing disabled for the same reasons. BUT, we were able to reduce the number of DB references by removing the "tags" attribute from the CE cache tags in the templates - we went from over 215,000 DB references to under 10,000 so that was significant! Ideally still though, we'd just prefer not to record the references in the DB at all, but this will get us by. Thanks again!